# Products with attributes (variants) database design?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web, database-design

Hello I have two tables with many to many relationship and a junction table.
In short, products with different attributes which have added price with them.
to make it more clear I It's product and attribute table.

`+-------------+-----------+-------------------+
 |   product   | attribute | attribute_product |
 +-------------+-----------+-------------------+
 | id          | id        | product_id        |
 | name        | name      | attribute_id      |
 | description |           | attribute_value   |
 | price       |           | added_price       |
 +-------------+-----------+-------------------+`

as Laravel doesn't support multi column primary key I want the `attribute_product` table to have a primary key and when I call `$product->attribute->attach()` it automatically increment it, so I can do the following :

`+---------+----------------------+
 |  cart   |     cart_product     |
 +---------+----------------------+
 | id      | cart_id              |
 | user_id | attribute_product_id |
 +---------+----------------------+`

In my head I'm gonna make a model for `attribute_product` table and call it `Item` and therefore a cart can have multiple Items, and I can show it like `$cart->items->groupBy('product_id')` so I can have it all there in the user's cart.

Any solution or a better suggestion is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that maybe you aren't focusing it in the right way. If you have a `belongsToMany` relationship between *product* and *attribute*, is because **a product may have multiple attributes without being a different product**.

In your cart you should add a product, not an specific attribute of a product. For example:

> I want a water bottle, but only the water, without the bottle.

This makes no sense, you can not buy a water bottle without the bottle. In that case you will be buying water, not a water bottle, which should be different products, not the same one.

The `cart_product` table should look like this, as long as there is no compelling reason why it can not be so.

```
 +---------+----------------------+
 |  cart   |     cart_product     |
 +---------+----------------------+
 | id      | cart_id              |
 | user_id | product_id           |
 +---------+----------------------+
```

Comment: So tell me, if a product for example has 2 values for one attribute e.g. size can be both Small and Large. How can I know that the product in the cart is Large or Small?

Comment: @ArmanMomeni okay, I see what you say. Anyway, a product should be a product, and people adds products to the cart. It can be possible with your approach, but what will happen when a product doesn't have different attributes? You will have to create a row when isn't needed. I think I will create a product for each size, and then relate them renaming the `attributes` table to something like `collections`. Then when you show a product you can also show the products of the same collection as different options, like amazon does when there are different options for a "same" product.

Comment: At the end, is supposed that each different size of the "same" product will have a different unique code on the backend. Of course, all depends on what you want at the end.